# Rotate+ Zoom in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

i have a query regarding the simultaneous operation of zoom and rotate the image at same time ....
actually i want to apply both rotation and zoom on image in as3 using TransformGestureEvent

Comment: What is your query? there are many examples out there doing zoom and rotate at the same time, this isn't a very specific question.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [Matrix class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix.html). Creating a variation from [this post](http://ryanbosinger.com/blog/2008/actionscript-30-rotate-around-center-point/):

```
function rotateAndZoom (
        ob:*, 
        angleDegrees:Number, 
        zoomAmt:Number, 
        ptRotationPoint:Point
) {
      var m:Matrix = ob.transform.matrix;

      m.tx -= ptRotationPoint.x;
      m.ty -= ptRotationPoint.y;

      m.rotate (angleDegrees*(Math.PI/180));
      m.scale(zoomAmt, zoomAmt);

      m.tx += ptRotationPoint.x;
      m.ty += ptRotationPoint.y;

      ob.transform.matrix = m;
 }
```

Let me know if this solves the problem.

Comment: if it worked then it solved your problem right? Then mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out gestures recognition library similar to Apple's UIGestureRecognizers https://github.com/fljot/Gestouch/tree/develop

Combined example here https://github.com/fljot/GestouchExamples/blob/develop/src/org/gestouch/examples/views/ConflictGesturesView.mxml